# Active Admin Devise User : Update Without Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, authentication, devise

I have a rails app where I am using devise for authentication. The model is User. I have also used active admin for the admin dashboard and created user resource within. A user has edit, view and delete link on the admin side and an edit form (provided by devise) on the normal user form.

I want to allow admin users to be able to change user's details on the active admin dashboard without needing to know their password. That means no validations on active admin side for user editing. How should I proceed with that ?

My admin/user.rb looks like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
    active_admin_importable
# See permitted parameters documentation:
# https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
#
 permit_params :email, :name, :role, :zipcode, :city, :street_address, :state, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation, :leads2dealscustomer, :slug, :verified,:tdcfinance ,:textcolor

  form do |f|
      f.inputs "User" do
        f.input :email
        f.input :name
        f.input :password
        f.input :password_confirmation
        f.input :role      
        f.input :street_address
        f.input :city
        f.input :state
        f.input :zipcode
        f.input :phone_number   
      end
      f.actions
    end

    scope :all_users
    scope :basic_users
    scope :basic_dealers
    scope :basic_repairshops
    scope :silver_dealers
    scope :silver_repairshops
    scope :gold_dealer
    scope :diamond_dealer

    scope :leads2deals


    controller do 
        def approve_users_listings_or_repairshops(user_id)
            begin
                Listing.where(:user_id => user_id).update_all(:approved => true)
                Repairshop.where(:user_id => user_id).update_all(:approved => true) 
                return true         
            rescue
                return false
            end
        end



        def hold_users_listings_or_repairshops(user_id)
            begin
                Listing.where(:user_id => user_id).update_all(:approved => false)
                Repairshop.where(:user_id => user_id).update_all(:approved => false)
                return true         
            rescue
                return false
            end
        end

        def give_leadstodeals_priviliges(user_id)
            begin
                User.find_by_id(user_id).update(:leads2dealscustomer => true)
                return true         
            rescue
                return false
            end
        end

        def verify_user(user_id)
            begin
                User.find_by_id(user_id).update(:verified => true)
                return true         
            rescue
                return false
            end
        end

        def give_tdcfinance_priviliges(user_id)
            begin
                User.find_by_id(user_id).update(:tdcfinance => true)
                return true         
            rescue
                return false
            end
        end
    end

    member_action :approve_users_listings_or_repairshops_method, method: :get do 
        status = approve_users_listings_or_repairshops(resource.id)
        if status 
            redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "Users Listings and Repairshops were approved"
        else
            redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "there was some error while approving this user's listings/repairshops"
        end
    end

     member_action :hold_users_listings_or_repairshops_method, method: :get do 
        status = hold_users_listings_or_repairshops(resource.id)
        if status 
            redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "Users Listings and Repairshops were put on hold"
        else
            redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "there was some error while putting hold on this user's listings/repairshops"
        end
    end

    member_action :give_leadstodeals_priviliges_method, method: :get do 
        status = give_leadstodeals_priviliges(resource.id)
        if status 
            redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "User given leads to deals leads"
        else
            redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "There was some error while converting this user to leads to deals"
        end
    end

    member_action :verify_user_method, method: :get do 
        status = verify_user(resource.id)
        if status 
            redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "User Verified"
        else
            redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "There was some error while converting this user"
        end
    end

    member_action :give_tdcfinance_priviliges_method, method: :get do 
        status = give_tdcfinance_priviliges(resource.id)
        if status 
            redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "User is now TDC Finance user"
        else
            redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "There was some error while converting this user"
        end
    end





    index do
        column :id
        column "Email", :email
        column "Name", :name
        column "Role", :role 


        column "Number of Listings" do |resource|
            resource.number_of_listings
        end

        column "Number of Repairshops" do |resource|
            resource.number_of_repairshops
        end

        column "Approve Users Listings/Repairshops" do |user|
            link_to "Yes approve all", approve_users_listings_or_repairshops_method_admin_user_path(user)
        end

        column "Hold all users Listings/Repairshops" do |user|
            link_to "Yes hold all", hold_users_listings_or_repairshops_method_admin_user_path(user)
        end

        column :verified
        column :leads2dealscustomer        
        column :tdcfinance 

        column "Verified user" do |user|
            link_to "Yes Verified",  verify_user_method_admin_user_path(user)
        end

        column "Convert user to leads 2 deals customer" do |user|
            link_to "Yes convert User",  give_leadstodeals_priviliges_method_admin_user_path(user)
        end

        column "Convert user to TDC Finance customer" do |user|
            link_to "Yes convert User",  give_tdcfinance_priviliges_method_admin_user_path(user)
        end



        column "Website", :website 
        column "Zipcode", :zipcode
        column "City", :city
        column "State", :state
        column "Street address", :street_address
        column "Phone", :phone_number

        column "" do |resource|
          links = ''.html_safe
          links += link_to I18n.t('active_admin.edit'), edit_resource_path(resource), :class => "member_link edit_link"
          links += link_to I18n.t('active_admin.view'), resource_path(resource), :class => "member_link view_link"
          links += link_to I18n.t('active_admin.delete'), resource_path(resource), :method => :delete, :confirm => I18n.t('active_admin.delete_confirmation'), :class => "member_link delete_link"
          links

        end

    end 



end
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to remove password params from params hash, in this case validation will pass

```
  before_action :remove_password_params_if_blank, only: [:update]
  controller do
    def remove_password_params_if_blank
      if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
        params[:user].delete(:password)
        params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use the permit_params block in the active admin file for the user (user.rb):

```
permit_params do
  permitted = [:email, :password, :password_confirmation]
  if params[:user] && params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
    params[:user].delete(:password)
    params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
  end
  permitted
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I think a better option is modify only the form like:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "User" do
    f.input :email
    f.input :name
    f.input :password if f.object.new_record?
    f.input :password_confirmation if f.object.new_record?
    f.input :role      
    f.input :street_address
    f.input :city
    f.input :state
    f.input :zipcode
    f.input :phone_number   
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: I'm not against this approach but I do feel adds too much logic to the view.
responsibility for this should lie in the controller or model. 
Maybe a middle ground if using rails would be in a helper? maybe

Comment: What if user wants to update the password ? I guess controller approach is more logical.